# Custom listview, view problems

Tags: java, android, listview

Im absolutely new in android studio, and Im trying to create custom listview, the problem is that it creating wrong list, as

```
Name
Name
------
Surname
Surname
-----
```

...  and repeating

what I want to do is:

```
Name
Surname
-------
```

My code is:

```
    protected void onResume() {
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < db.getAllContacts().size(); i++) {
        names.add(db.getAllContacts().get(i).getName());
                names.add(db.getAllContacts().get(i).getEmail());

    }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new custom_row(this, names);
        listView_allContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onResume();
    }
```

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

My custom_row code:

public class custom_row extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public custom_row(Context context, ArrayList<String> names) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_cell, names);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater peoInf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = peoInf.inflate(R.layout.custom_cell, parent , false);
    String singlePeople = getItem(position);
    TextView name_text = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
    TextView email_text = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.email_text);

    name_text.setText(singlePeople);
    email_text.setText(singlePeople);
    return customView;
}
```

}

Comment: What's `custom_row` class?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to help you. We need to see the `custom_row` class (which isn't a row, it's an Adapter, and that displays many rows, so I'd suggest renaming that). Then we also need to see the XML layout of a single row

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with an [edit] to your question

Comment: In any case, don't extract the name and email from the list outside of the Adapter... Ideally, you should pass `db.getAllContacts()` into the adapter. Then, call `getItem(position)` within the `getView` of the adapter class, and set the data on appropriate xml views

Answer (score 0):

You need two different ArrayList one for the Names and one for the email.

try this

```
ArrayList<String> list;

public custom_row(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> email) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_cell, names);
    list = email;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater peoInf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = peoInf.inflate(R.layout.custom_cell, parent , false);
    String singlePeople = getItem(position);
    String email = list.get(position);
    TextView name_text = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
    TextView email_text = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.email_text);

     name_text.setText(singlePeople);
    email_text.setText(email);
    return customView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps!

Comment: The problem is then I adding searchBox it searches only names column, is it possible to make email search too?